# Laravel - Using joins with where across two tables

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have table, 'jobs', indexed by job_id, and and table discussions with foreign key 'job_id'.

In jobs I have a column called 'summary', and in discussions a column called 'body'. I want to search for the same text string in both of these columns across both these tables and return the applicable jobs.

Eg, if a jobs record with job_id=7 has the string 'somestring' in it's 'summary' column, and a discussions record has foreign key job_id=20 and has string 'somestring', I want the job records for job_id=7 and job_id=20 returned.

I am using laravel. I'm having trouble finding a solution, this is the closest I have got:

```
$query->join('discussions', function( $join ) use ( $search_term ){
                $join->on('jobs.job_id', '=', 'discussions.job_id');
                $join->where('discussions.body', 'LIKE', $search_term );                    
                $join->orWhere('jobs.summary', 'LIKE', $search_term );                                  
            })
```

But this just returns everything from my discussions table. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's SQL problem with that. What you are doing is basically this:

```
SELECT * FROM jobs INNER JOIN discussions ON (...) jobs.summary LIKE search_term
```

There is no `WHERE` clause, and that part `(...)` doesn't matter (simplified a bit) since there is `OR`, so in fact you don't (not only) join the table on the key/fk pair.

You simply need to move those `where`s out of the join closure and it will work as expected:

```
$query->join('discussions', function( $join ) {
     $join->on('jobs.job_id', '=', 'discussions.job_id');
})
    ->where('discussions.body', 'LIKE', $search_term )
    ->orWhere('jobs.summary', 'LIKE', $search_term )
    ->get();
```

Now your query will look like it should:

```
SELECT * FROM jobs INNER JOIN discussions ON jobs.id = discussions.job_id 
    WHERE discussions.body LIKE search_term
    OR jobs.summary LIKE search_term
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I followed what you have put above, and although the query does render as you say, I still am only getting back the results from my discussions table. The jobs that have the text in the jobs.summary are being ignored.

Comment: The query is OK for sure, but maybe you need `leftJoin` instead of (inner) `join` then?

Comment: Cheers, the leftJoin has done the trick in that I am getting back the correct result now :) Thank you very much. However it job_id field is now empty in the results that have come back from the jobs table. Any idea why that could be happening?

Comment: Do you know the difference between `inner join` and `left join`? You will get all the matching results from the 'left' table (also those that don't have related job, thus `job_id` might be empty for some of them).

Comment: Not really, my MySQL is weak. Will look it up in detail. Thanks for taking the time to go through this. Will mark as accepted answer as although I haven't got exactly what I want, I understand what I have got and why :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this and see what comes out of it ;)

```
$query->join('discussions', function( $join ) use ( $search_term ){
                $join->on('jobs.job_id', '=', 'discussions.job_id')
                 ->where('discussions.body', 'LIKE', $search_term )                    
                 ->orWhere('jobs.summary', 'LIKE', $search_term );                               
            })
      ->select('*')
      ->get();
```

**EDIT:** I would replace the `$query` with the correct `DB::table('mytable')`.

```
DB::table('jobs')->join('discussions', function( $join ) use ( $search_term ){
                $join->on('jobs.job_id', '=', 'discussions.job_id')
                 ->where('discussions.body', 'LIKE', $search_term )                    
                 ->orWhere('jobs.summary', 'LIKE', $search_term );                               
            })
      ->select('*')
      ->get();
```

**EDIT2:** I missed a semicolumn, corrected

Comment: then you have to be more specific with the select clause @Ste77